# Typescript module import issue

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, leaflet

I'm using angular 5 with @types/leaflet.  I want to draw curves as well so I'm attempting to use @types/leaflet-curve.   The issue I'm having is the curve function is not being imported for some reason.  The error I'm getting is

> "Property 'curve' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   ".../node_modules/@types/leaflet-curve/index"'

I have the import in the map.ts file as import * as lc from 'leaflet-curve'.  I've tried different types of imports but nothing seems to work and I'm unsure if it's my typescript version (2.5.x) or something else I haven't done.

The index.d.ts file for leaflet-curve is as follows;

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';

declare module 'leaflet' {
    /**
     * Drawing Bezier curves and other complex shapes.
     */
    function curve(path: any[], options?: PathOptions): Path;
}
```

I'm attempting to use the function as such:

```
var curves = lc.curve([[s.lat, s.long],[d.lat, d.long]], {})
```

Comment: What's lc defined as?

Comment: @rrd That’s what I import the module as. Import * as lc from leaflet-curve